# Why does magnesium have the lowest melting point of all earth alkalis?

Tags: melting-point

Why does magnesium have the lowest melting point of all earth alkali metals?

Comment: Perhaps you could give us the data for the rest of the alkali metals and explain why this is surprising to you.

Comment: [This website](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group2/properties.html) seems to make a good argument that the cause of magnesium's low melting point is not understood (see the "Trends in Melting Point, Boiling Point, and Atomisation Energy" section).  The page also discusses why the reasons typically advanced probably aren't valid.